# Wordpress Update Issue with permission

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I had problem to update (automatically and manually) my wordpress on my server. Always got permission problem. I tried to changed the permission but then I can not access at all to my wordpress website. I don't know if it is permission problem? I put most of the files and directory in 774 to try but still can not open any page always got HTTP ERROR 500. Any idea where should I check?

Comment: try comment the htaccess file and create the new default .htaccess file from the link :-  https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess  only basic one

Comment: @TechnoDeviser my htaccess file is same as the default wordpress one. I just checked that. Same as here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45898/default-htaccess-file-for-wordpress